# ValueError at /content/search Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 8

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

я пытаюсь реализовать поиск по нескольким таблицам в базе данных. Для этого я написал вот такую функцию во views.py:

```
def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('search','')
    if search_query:
        post1 = plants.objects.filter(Q(latin_name__icontains=search_query) | Q(name__icontains=search_query))
        post2 = shrimp.objects.filter(Q(latin_name__icontains=search_query) | Q(name__icontains=search_query))
        post3 = snail.objects.filter(Q(latin_name__icontains=search_query) | Q(name__icontains=search_query))
        post4 = snag.objects.filter(Q(latin_name__icontains=search_query) | Q(name__icontains=search_query))

    else:
        post1 = plants.objects.all()
        post2 = shrimp.objects.all()
        post3 = snail.objects.all()
        post4 = snag.objects.all()
    result = [('растения', post1),('креветки', post2),('улитки', post3), ('коряги', post4)]
    return render(request,'content/search.html', context={'results': result})
```

search.html:

```
{% extends 'main_page/main_page.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block css %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/search.css' %}"/>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container-content">
    {% for result in results %}
      {% for name, element in result %}
        <p>{{ name }}</p>
        <div class="container-content-block">
          <div class="text">{{ element.latin_name }}</div>
          <div class="image">
            <img src="/{{ element.image.url }}/" alt="картинка не работает" width="170" height="200">
          </div>
          <div class="text">{{ element.price }} руб</div>
          <div class="text">{{ element.name }}</div>
          <form action="{% url 'add_to_basket' element.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="В корзину">
          </form>
          <a href="{% url 'plants_info' element.id %}">
            <input class="btn btn-light" type="submit" value="Подробнее">
          </a>
          <!-- <input class="btn btn-success" value="В корзину" type="submit"> -->
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

это всё выдает мне ошибку "ValueError at /content/search
Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 8. " в месте, где вызывается функция render, но я не понимаю, как как её решить. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: приложите traceback. Вопрос некоректный так как нету МВП

Comment: покажите шаблон `'content/search.html'`

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для первого варианта кода, поясняю

Проблема в 2 строках

```
    {% for result in results %}
      {% for name, element in result %}
```

Почему? Потому что у вас массив кортежей 
    `result = [('растения', post1),('креветки', post2),('улитки', post3), ('коряги', post4)]`

При первом `for`, вы перебираете кортежи. И вроде бы все верно, НО. Во второй строчке, вы снова пытаетесь перебрать элементы, но указав поля через запятую, вы говорите питону, что ожидаете распаковки значений. Поэтому и вознкает ошибка.

Есть 2 решения, красивое и не очень

1

```
    {% for name, element in results %}
```

2

```
    {% for result in results %}
        {% with result.0 as name %}
            {% with result.1 as element %}
```

Не за что :)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю переделать кортежи в словарь:

```
def a(request):
    result = [{'растения': 'a'},{'креветки': 'b'},{'улитки': 'c'}, {'коряги': 'd'}]
    return render(request,'app/search.html', context={'results': result})
```

```
{% for result in results %}
  {% for x, y in result.items %}
    {{ x }} - {{ y }}</br>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

```
растения - a
креветки - b
улитки - c
коряги - d
```

Comment: теперь результаты поиска вообще не отображаются, но ошибка ушла

Comment: это уже другой вопрос вообще должен быть. обновите ваш код вьюхи и шаблона.

Comment: все, я решил проблему. По сути я просто переделал result в словарь.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 у вас та же проблема. ваш вариант не работает. можете проверить. почему - смотрите ответ ниже

Comment: @ZaArs вполне себе работает, если в словарь преобразовать)

Comment: ```{% for result in results %}
  {% for x, y in result.items %}
    {{ x }} - {{ y }}</br>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}``` если results - словарь, то будет перебирать ключи, тогда вторая строка не сработает

Comment: для словаря надо почти также как в моем варианте `{% for key, value in results.items %}`